# PATCH method handler on Google AppEngine WebApp2

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, http-patch

I tried to use a `def patch():` method in my `webapp2.RequestHandler` to support partial resource updates, but then saw that the allowed methods are frozen in webapp2.py:

```
allowed_methods = frozenset(('GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT',
                             'DELETE', 'TRACE'))
```

How can I extend `webapp2.RequestHandler` or modify the `WSGIApplication` class to allow the PATCH HTTP method when deployed on Google AppEngine?

Comment: As a workaround, you could implement the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` as Google does for their own APIs: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.de/2012/03/making-patch-requests-from-app-engine.html

Answer (score 15):

Just use a monkey patch by performing this before creating a `WSGIApplication`:

```
allowed_methods = webapp2.WSGIApplication.allowed_methods
new_allowed_methods = allowed_methods.union(('PATCH',))
webapp2.WSGIApplication.allowed_methods = new_allowed_methods
```

There is a current [patch](https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=69) on the `webapp2` issue tracker but no one has picked it up.