# dev_appserver.py locally rejects PATCH requests but accepts it on deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, backbone.js, django-rest-framework, djangoappengine

I've got an app based on djangoappengine, Backbone.js and Django REST Framework that uses PATCH requests to update models via `{patch: true}` on a `model.save` call.

I've found that when testing locally the dev_appserver returns:

`ERROR    2014-02-19 04:37:04,531 dev_appserver.py:3081] code 501, message Unsupported method ('PATCH')`

`INFO     2014-02-19 04:37:04,532 dev_appserver.py:3090] "PATCH /api/posts/5707702298738688 HTTP/1.1" 501 -`

Yet when I deploy it and access it through appspot the server happily accepts the request. Which forces me to deploy every time I make a change and want to test it.

I'm running the latests version (1.89) of the Python SDK, and found and [old fixed issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6316) that seems to tackle it but it seems [other people have had it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280496/patch-method-handler-on-google-appengine-webapp2).

I tried [this patch](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=69) but it didn't make a difference. I don't understand why the development server would reject them and not the production server, is there something I need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: That fixed issue concerns the PATCH method in the URL Fetch Service, not the development web server.  [Issue 975](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=975) says PROPPPATCH could be fixed for WebDAV support, and that PATCH is still unsupported on the development web server :-(

Answer (score 0):

To update a resource, you can use POST with the x-http-method-override to patch. This is a valid RESTful operation and using POST will be more compatible with firewall and older user agents. The data in the request should indicate what is to be updated.

```
var url = '/api/posts/5707702298738688'
var patch_ops =  [
        { "op": "replace", "path": "/properties/", "author": text}
        { "op": "add", "path": "/replies/", {"author": text, "comment":"blah"}}
        /*
            { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
            { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
            { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
            { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
            { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" } 
       */
    ];

 var xhr = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
        },
        url: url,
        data: my_json_string,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
              return error;
        }
    });
```

Server handler:

```
def post(self, object_name):
    if self.request.headers['x-http-method-override'] == 'PATCH':
        # update according to patch operations
        patch_ops_str= self.request.body.decode('utf-8')    
        try:
            patch_ops = json.loads(new_area_geojson_str)
        except:
            self.response.set_status(400)
            return self.response.out.write('{"status": "error", "reason": "JSON Parse error" }')

     else:
         self.response.set_status(405)
         return self.response.out.write('{"status": "error", "reason": "post not accepted without x-http-method-override to PATCH" }')
```

Adapted from [Please do not patch like an idiot](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/)